# Proving that only one function solves Kepler's equation.

Tags: calculus

Prove that there exists only one continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies Kepler's equation

$$f\left(x\right)-\epsilon\sin\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=x$$

where $\epsilon$ is between $0$ and $1$.
 Any hint will help a lot.

Comment: Consider the equation $y-\epsilon\sin y=x$ and determine the number of solutions in $y$.

Comment: Thank you!
I will try.

Comment: Other hint: is $y-\epsilon\sin y$ monotonic ?

Comment: I managed to prove that it has an inverse function. And derived from that that F(x) should be equal to the inverse. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yep, then for every $x$, $f(x)$ is uniquely defined.

Comment: Yea! :D
Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the equation possess two solutions say $y_1$ and $y_2$ and let $z=y_1-y_2$. Then we have $$z=\varepsilon \big (\sin y_1-\sin y_2\big).$$ By the mean value theorem $$|z|=\varepsilon|\sin y_1-\sin y_2|\leq \varepsilon |z|.$$ This implies that $\varepsilon \geq 1$ which is a conttradiction since  $0<\varepsilon<1$ given. Thus $y_1=y_2$ .